# equally divide the dimension data into 2 different calculated field

Tags: tableau-api

I want to equally divide the dimension data into 2 different calculated field in such a way that these two calculated field not showing any null records across them when place into row shelf.
    E.g Suppose I have a dimension user having data like 'AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'EF'
    Expected output -
    Calculated field1      Calculated field2
    AB                       CD 
    BC                       EF

```
I have achieved the calculated fields functionality. However, I am not able to do it align properly-
Below is not valid output. I want to remove NULLS
Calculated field1      Calculated field2
AB                       NULL 
BC                       NULL
NULL                      CD
NULL                      EF
```

Comment: Its not really clear what the final output you want is? If you just want to remove NULLS dimension heading from the calculated field you could just add an if clause like so: IF ISNULL([your dimension]) THEN "Text instead of NULL"
ELSE [your dimension]
END

Comment: Instead of null I don't want any blank record. Simply delete that Nulls.

Comment: Can you not just drag both calculated also into the filter area, select null, and click the check box to exclude selected option?

Comment: it excludes entire row